# How to use Llama.cpp with LangChain in TS?

Tags: typescript, langchain, llama

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /.../node_modules/node-llama-cpp/dist/index.js from /.../node_modules/langchain/dist/util/llama_cpp.cjs not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /.../node_modules/langchain/dist/util/llama_cpp.cjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Because of this error, I added `"type": "module",` to `package.json` file. If I do then I get `: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /.../index.ts`

When I try `ts-node-esm index.ts` from the solution I'd found here, it returns `ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope`.

How can I use LangChain with my Llama.cpp on .ts?

Comment: use `npx tsx index.ts`

Comment: now i am getting ` Top-level await is currently not supported with the "cjs" output format` :')

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I suggest you use `vite-node`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd found why it was happening. My llama.cpp was made for x86 not arm chip!